# Orbital Chinese firework-cluster

Tags: design-alternative

I remember when I was younger I had heard this story about the Chinese using primitive fireworks, and even strapping them to a bamboo glider in an attempt to reach the moon. This story probably isn't even true, and I shudder to think of the t/w and isp those fireworks would provide, but would it be possible to strap enough of them together to reach orbit, somewhat similarly to [OTRAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTRAG_(rocket)), and how ridiculously large would it have to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very [crude back-of-the-envelope math](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8720/195) suggests that a rocket of about one million tons -- 300 times the mass of the Saturn V -- could reach orbit on black powder from a specific impulse and mass ratio standpoint. Whether it's possible to structurally assemble a rocket of that size and launch it is questionable, at best.

Comment: what would the dimensions of such a rocket be(number of stages, height, width, relation between payload capacity and size of rocket)?

Comment: As per my linked answer to a different question, it's 8 stages, each stage 5 times the mass of the one above it, with a payload of 2.5 tons to orbit from the 1 million ton liftoff mass. Working out the dimensions is left as an exercise.

Comment: @RussellBorogove ...or a 32 gram chip-sat, on a bit over 3-ton (3125kg) rocket (starting off with 1st stage of 2.5 ton - I was checking how much could be shaved off your launch mass by going with smaller final stage that's still not useless, and managed to shave off *all* of it.)

Comment: Scaling at that end is going to depart dramatically from the theoretical.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Russell Borogove's answer there is also the XKCD design using modern model [rocket motors](https://what-if.xkcd.com/24/) and a complex staging profile that got an orbital vehicle that is 'an unstable pile of gunpowder the size of Central Park' and the [British Interplanetary society](https://www.bis-space.com/what-we-do/projects/bis-lunar-spaceship) black powder design that I cannot find numbers on beyond 5 stages and 'the mass of an ocean liner'. Most of the BIS design work was expended on the instrumentation and guidance of the lander rather than the launch vehicle.