# Escape Velocity

Tags: orbital-mechanics, rockets

I've read that if the Earth was 50% larger, escape velocity would be so great that we could not build a powerful enough rocket to escape. Is this true and how do I do the maths to prove it?

Comment: I assume you mean *chemical* rocket. Orion has a rather larger potential thrust/weight ratio. (You might also want to clarify that you mean radius, as opposed to mass.)

Comment: I meant radius, and chemical rockets ( or any other technology if it would be better)

Comment: Asked before. http://space.stackexchange.com/q/5320/265, http://space.stackexchange.com/q/17423/265, http://space.stackexchange.com/q/14383/265 .

Comment: Duplicate of [How much bigger could Earth be, before rockets would't work?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/5320/4660). I believe the aspect of how to do the math is covered in the answer by Hohmannfan, and additional aspects are covered in the answer by Russell Borogove. Please comment if you need more information on the math. The questions pointed out by Mark Adler have some additional information.