# How massive can a planet become before it is impossible to escape from using chemical rocket propulsion?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch, gravity

Assuming a vaguely Earth like world but with higher gravity, at what point is it no longer possible to launch a human being from the surface into orbit? Or anything into orbit?

Comment: See also https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/on-a-super-earth-1-5x-the-volume-and-mass-of-earth-would-our-rocket-technology?noredirect=1&lq=1